# Links to .org files are not recognized as links in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I've been trying to use links in my org files but it doesn't work as I'd expect. It works as is should - convert `[[target][Desc]]` to `Desc` and make it clickable for any target, except when the target ends with `.org`. Then it is just the "raw" text version. 
I've tested in on an empty init.el with the same result.

```
[[file:~/test.or][Works]]
[[file:~/test.org][Does not work]]
[[file:~/test.org-][Works]]
```

[image: emacs]
Whenever  I change the org extension either by adding a letter or subracting one, it folds the link properly.
What should I adjust to fix it?

Emacs version: emacs-26.3-z-mac-7.8

Thanks!

Comment: This works fine for me.  What is your org-mode version?  Do you change any standard settings?

Comment: The org version is 9.1.9. I ralize that it should work by default but for some reason I can't get it working even when the config is the default one for emacs. So there is probably something wrong on my system but I'd need help to find the problem.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what you see?

Comment: AFAIK fontification of org-links is the job of font-lock. At first you could check the Messages buffer. Maybe, it indicates what goes wrong. As a second option you could you use [font-lock-studio](https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio) to step through the fontification rules. [`font-lock-studio`](https://melpa.org/#/?q=font-lock-studio) is available via Melpa. Input `M-x font-lock-studio` when you are in your org file use the `Font Lock Studio` menu to step through the rules. If something goes wrong the debugger will give you a backtrace. You could post that backtrace here.

Comment: Maybe related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55766/org-mode-prettifies-url-links-but-not-file-links

Comment: Are you using the `org-roam` package? I'm having this same issue with the same version of org as you. https://github.com/jethrokuan/org-roam/issues/180

Comment: Yes, it seems that `org-roam` is the problem. My bad that I somehow didn't unload it when I was testing the problem with an empty init.el. With vanilla emacs it works as it should. It stops when I load `org-roam`. Thank you all for help.

Comment: Not sure whether this should be here, but I've answered (with your help!) my own question below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to `org-roam` library. 
Upgrading `org` to `9.3.6-17-g389288-elpa`fixes the problem.

This is how you can upgrade `org` which by default is a built-in library.
Add to `init.el`

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

Reload emacs and run `M-x list-packages RET`.

Find `org` and you'll see two available versions. Install the one from orgmode elpa.

After restarting, the newer version should be run (which you can confirm by `M-x org-version`).

Comment: can't build latest orgmode on m1 mac so I am stuck there. my version is 9.1.5 for what it is worth.