# org-mode "prettifies" URL links, but not file links

Tags: org-mode, org-link

The org-mode [documentation](https://orgmode.org/guide/Hyperlinks.html) says that

> Once a link in the buffer is complete, with all brackets present, Org changes the display so that ‘DESCRIPTION’ is displayed instead of ‘[[LINK][DESCRIPTION]]’ and ‘LINK’ is displayed instead of ‘[[LINK]]’.

If I type

```
[[https://www.calebjay.com][website]]
```

When I finish the final bracket and press `SPC`, indeed the links shortens to only show the word `website`. This is what I want.

However, if I type

```
[[file:test.org][test]]
```

This does not shorten. It always displays in the raw as above. If I put my cursor over `test` and press `ENTER`, a new window opens with that (existent) file opened.

How can I make the file link behavior mirror that of a website?

EDIT: I highlighted an entire link and ran `font-lock-studio-region`, which output a 200 line file. One thing I noticed is a line that says

```
org-activate-links
  (0 nil)
```

I wonder if that has something to do with it. The whole file can be found at https://pastebin.com/REzWfG53

My versions:

GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16

Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /home/caleb/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-20191230/)

Ubuntu 18.04.04 64bit

Comment: Prettifies for me. Could you try with emacs -q?

Comment: Maybe related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55720/links-to-org-files-are-not-recognized-as-links-in-org-mode You should perhaps add all version info: emacs-version, org-version, OS-version Could be we can detect an error scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the cross link. Let me try that font lock thing. I tried swapping out extensions for like .txt or just none at all and it still didn't fold. But I do suspect it's something with font-lock based on vague other googling I was doing.

Comment: Actually, changing the extension from .org did cause it to "collapse" properly. Super weird.

Comment: It may have something to do with the `org-roam` package https://github.com/jethrokuan/org-roam/issues/180